# Stripping "track numbers" from a string

Tags: php, string

I am writing a small music playing web app, and had a problem I couldn't figure out a solution to. Music files often start with a two digit track number, eg:

`02 Hiding Place (Mudule Remix).m4a`

or `15 An Afternoon on the Moon (Jet Jaguar Remix).m4a`

How can a PHP script detect the `## *` rule and remove the numbers and space at the start of the string?

I thought of looping through the first 3 characters and checking if they were numbers and spaces, then removing with `substr`, is that the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo ltrim('02 Hiding Place (Mudule Remix).m4a', ' 0123456789');
```

see: [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/function.ltrim.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was definitely the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of looping through the first 3 characters and checking if they were numbers and spaces, then removing with substr, is that the best way?

This seems like the simplest approach and there's no room for serious optimization for such a simple task, so I would recommend this approach.

You also remove it using a regular expression, but that would be slightly slower due to the overhead.